# Suspension of Diffeomorphisms

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, foliations

There is no doubt that **Suspension of Diffeomorphisms** is a special case of **Suspension of a Representation** (that is also known as **Suspension of Diffeomorphism Group**). Therefore, I would be very grateful if highly recommended references on this special case were able to be pointed out.

Comment: So, what is your question? What's unclear to you with either definition?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am looking for highly recommended references on suspension of diffeomorphisms

Comment: If you understand the definition, what kind of a reference do you need and why? Do you need a reference relating dynamical properties of diffeomorphisms to that of their suspensions?

Comment: @MoisheKohan my main aim is to understand the general case that is suspensions of a representation but I started from the special case that is suspensions of diffeomorphisms. Therefore, what kind of references would you prefer to suggest?